# How to hide the Page Object Initialization within the Test Framework in Java

Tags: java, c#, selenium, frameworks

I am starting with selenium in java but in c # I have some more experience.

I want to know if it's possible hide the Page Object Initialization within the Test Framework in Java.

In c # I know how to make it using generic type T  and Constraints

```
public static class Page {

    private static T GetPage<T>() where T : new()
    {
        var page = new T();
        PageFactory.InitElements(BrowserFactory.Driver, page);       
        return page;
    }

    public static HomePage Home
    {
        get { return GetPage<HomePage>(); }
    }
}
```

and the call in my test would be:

```
{...

    Page.Home.ClickOnMyAccount()

...}
```

where ClickOnMyAccountwould be a method of home class

I don't know if this is possible to do java? and how would it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PageFactory.InitElements` returns an instance of the class, you can return it

```
public static class Page {
    private static <T> T GetPage(Class<T> page) {
        return PageFactory.InitElements(BrowserFactory.Driver, page);       
    }

    public static HomePage getHomePage() {
        return Page.GetPage(HomePage.class);
    }
}
```

Uses

```
Page.getHomePage().ClickOnMyAccount();
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your inilization inside the constructor. Like:

```
public Page(){
    PageFactory.InitElements(BrowserFactory.Driver, this);
}
```

I think you just need to add this  constructor to you your page.